# Getting file through FTP using shell script

Tags: unix, ftp

I am trying to get the csv file from remote server through FTP using unix script.I am facing a wired problem here.File is not being fetched all the time.
Something it gets the file sometime it dose not.

```
ftp -v -i -n <<EOF > $log_path/

 open $FTP_SITE
 user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
 ascii
 hash
 passive

 cd Training_Uploads 
 mget  *.csv 
 pwd
 quit                     
 EOF
```

Comment: add a `dir` after the `cd` inside your block of ftp commands, you may be facing a timing issue. This way you'll know "YES, file is there or NO it wasn't there, even though somebody told it should be". Good luck.

Comment: I tried Dir the way you suggested...but ftp log says it did nit find the file, Actually file is there.

Answer (score 0):

'ftp' is so 80s! Why don't you move up the foodchain a little?

```
wget --user="${FTP_USER}" --password="${FTP_PASS}" "${FTP_SITE}/dir/files"
```

wget supports the FTP protocol and can continue interrupted downloads, can exclude files, can do recursive retrieval and just about anything.